# How does tree-shakable service avoid cyclic dependency whereas pre-Angular 6 DI does not?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

First of all, I create a function to be passed in `useFactory`:

```js
// circular.factory.ts

export let circularFactory = (instance: MyService) => {
  console.log('calling useFactory with:', instance);
  return instance || new MyService()
}
```

***Now I'm going to configure DI so that the service references the factory and the factory references the service.***

### First scenario:

Here I made use of pre-angular 6 DI way configuring it with `providers` array on the `NgModule` of my `AppModule`.

```js
// app.module.ts

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{
    deps: [
      [MyService]
    ],
    provide: MyService,
    useFactory: circularFactory
  }]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Running that will result in the following error:

> Error: Provider parse errors:
>   Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! MyService ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1

Well, that's to be expected. Indeed, I created a cyclic dependency.

### Second scenario:

This time I will configure DI using the `@Injectable()` `providedIn` property to refer to the root.

```js
// my.service.ts

@Injectable({
  deps: [
    [MyService]
  ],
  providedIn: 'root',
  useFactory: circularFactory
})
export class MyService {
  constructor() {
    console.log('instantiating MyService') 
  }
}

...

// app.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: `
    <h1>Oh, hi, there.</h1>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public myService: MyService) {
    console.log('injecting dependency into AppComponent:', this.myService);
  }
}
```

As you can see I've added a few console logs for debugging purposes. The results are as follows:

```
calling useFactory with: undefined
instantiating MyService
injecting dependency into AppComponent:
```

As opposed to the first case it somehow managed to resolve the token for `useFactory` into `undefined`. But how come? Shouldn't it fail with an error of cycling dependency as in the first example? Isn't it supposed to work the same way? I can't get it.

Here is the [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dsafsadfwefpoewqfwqef?file=app%2Fcounter.service.ts) you can run.